# SQL Server Naming Policy Management blocking correctly named stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to enforce a naming convention for user stored procedures to begin with 'usp_'. I created a policy and I receive an error no matter what the name of the stored procedure.

The condition is as follows:

```
DECLARE @condition_id INT

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_syspolicy_add_condition 
          @name = N'con_multipart_name_usp_prefix', 
          @description = N'',  
          @facet = N'IMultipartNameFacet', 
          @expression = N'<Operator>
                          <TypeClass>Bool</TypeClass>
                          <OpType>LIKE</OpType>
                          <Count>2</Count>
                          <Attribute>
                              <TypeClass>String</TypeClass>
                              <Name>Name</Name>
                          </Attribute>
                          <Constant>
                              <TypeClass>String</TypeClass>
                              <ObjType>System.String</ObjType>
                              <Value>usp_%</Value>
                          </Constant>
                       </Operator>', 
          @is_name_condition = 2, 
          @obj_name = N'usp_%', 
          @condition_id = @condition_id OUTPUT

SELECT @condition_id
GO
```

[Here is the SSMS properties box for the condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rd2NX.png)

The policy is as follows:

```
Declare @object_set_id int
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_syspolicy_add_object_set @object_set_name=N'policy_naming_usp_prefix_ObjectSet', @facet=N'IMultipartNameFacet', @object_set_id=@object_set_id OUTPUT
Select @object_set_id

Declare @target_set_id int
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_syspolicy_add_target_set @object_set_name=N'policy_naming_usp_prefix_ObjectSet', @type_skeleton=N'Server/Database/Sequence', @type=N'SEQUENCE', @enabled=False, @target_set_id=@target_set_id OUTPUT
Select @target_set_id

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_syspolicy_add_target_set_level @target_set_id=@target_set_id, @type_skeleton=N'Server/Database/Sequence', @level_name=N'Sequence', @condition_name=N'', @target_set_level_id=0
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_syspolicy_add_target_set_level @target_set_id=@target_set_id, @type_skeleton=N'Server/Database', @level_name=N'Database', @condition_name=N'', @target_set_level_id=0

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_syspolicy_add_target_set @object_set_name=N'policy_naming_usp_prefix_ObjectSet', @type_skeleton=N'Server/Database/StoredProcedure', @type=N'PROCEDURE', @enabled=True, @target_set_id=@target_set_id OUTPUT
Select @target_set_id

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_syspolicy_add_target_set_level @target_set_id=@target_set_id, @type_skeleton=N'Server/Database/StoredProcedure', @level_name=N'StoredProcedure', @condition_name=N'', @target_set_level_id=0
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_syspolicy_add_target_set_level @target_set_id=@target_set_id, @type_skeleton=N'Server/Database', @level_name=N'Database', @condition_name=N'', @target_set_level_id=0

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_syspolicy_add_target_set @object_set_name=N'policy_naming_usp_prefix_ObjectSet', @type_skeleton=N'Server/Database/Synonym', @type=N'SYNONYM', @enabled=False, @target_set_id=@target_set_id OUTPUT
Select @target_set_id

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_syspolicy_add_target_set_level @target_set_id=@target_set_id, @type_skeleton=N'Server/Database/Synonym', @level_name=N'Synonym', @condition_name=N'', @target_set_level_id=0
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_syspolicy_add_target_set_level @target_set_id=@target_set_id, @type_skeleton=N'Server/Database', @level_name=N'Database', @condition_name=N'', @target_set_level_id=0

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_syspolicy_add_target_set @object_set_name=N'policy_naming_usp_prefix_ObjectSet', @type_skeleton=N'Server/Database/Table', @type=N'TABLE', @enabled=False, @target_set_id=@target_set_id OUTPUT
Select @target_set_id

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_syspolicy_add_target_set_level @target_set_id=@target_set_id, @type_skeleton=N'Server/Database/Table', @level_name=N'Table', @condition_name=N'', @target_set_level_id=0
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_syspolicy_add_target_set_level @target_set_id=@target_set_id, @type_skeleton=N'Server/Database', @level_name=N'Database', @condition_name=N'', @target_set_level_id=0

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_syspolicy_add_target_set @object_set_name=N'policy_naming_usp_prefix_ObjectSet', @type_skeleton=N'Server/Database/UserDefinedFunction', @type=N'FUNCTION', @enabled=False, @target_set_id=@target_set_id OUTPUT
Select @target_set_id

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_syspolicy_add_target_set_level @target_set_id=@target_set_id, @type_skeleton=N'Server/Database/UserDefinedFunction', @level_name=N'UserDefinedFunction', @condition_name=N'', @target_set_level_id=0
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_syspolicy_add_target_set_level @target_set_id=@target_set_id, @type_skeleton=N'Server/Database', @level_name=N'Database', @condition_name=N'', @target_set_level_id=0

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_syspolicy_add_target_set @object_set_name=N'policy_naming_usp_prefix_ObjectSet', @type_skeleton=N'Server/Database/UserDefinedType', @type=N'TYPE', @enabled=False, @target_set_id=@target_set_id OUTPUT
Select @target_set_id

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_syspolicy_add_target_set_level @target_set_id=@target_set_id, @type_skeleton=N'Server/Database/UserDefinedType', @level_name=N'UserDefinedType', @condition_name=N'', @target_set_level_id=0
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_syspolicy_add_target_set_level @target_set_id=@target_set_id, @type_skeleton=N'Server/Database', @level_name=N'Database', @condition_name=N'', @target_set_level_id=0

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_syspolicy_add_target_set @object_set_name=N'policy_naming_usp_prefix_ObjectSet', @type_skeleton=N'Server/Database/View', @type=N'VIEW', @enabled=False, @target_set_id=@target_set_id OUTPUT
Select @target_set_id

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_syspolicy_add_target_set_level @target_set_id=@target_set_id, @type_skeleton=N'Server/Database/View', @level_name=N'View', @condition_name=N'', @target_set_level_id=0
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_syspolicy_add_target_set_level @target_set_id=@target_set_id, @type_skeleton=N'Server/Database', @level_name=N'Database', @condition_name=N'', @target_set_level_id=0

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_syspolicy_add_target_set @object_set_name=N'policy_naming_usp_prefix_ObjectSet', @type_skeleton=N'Server/Database/XmlSchemaCollection', @type=N'XMLSCHEMACOLLECTION', @enabled=False, @target_set_id=@target_set_id OUTPUT
Select @target_set_id

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_syspolicy_add_target_set_level @target_set_id=@target_set_id, @type_skeleton=N'Server/Database/XmlSchemaCollection', @level_name=N'XmlSchemaCollection', @condition_name=N'', @target_set_level_id=0
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_syspolicy_add_target_set_level @target_set_id=@target_set_id, @type_skeleton=N'Server/Database', @level_name=N'Database', @condition_name=N'', @target_set_level_id=0


GO

Declare @policy_id int
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_syspolicy_add_policy @name=N'policy_naming_usp_prefix', @condition_name=N'con_multipart_name_usp_prefix', @policy_category=N'', @description=N'', @help_text=N'', @help_link=N'', @schedule_uid=N'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', @execution_mode=1, @is_enabled=True, @policy_id=@policy_id OUTPUT, @root_condition_name=N'', @object_set=N'policy_naming_usp_prefix_ObjectSet'
Select @policy_id


GO
```

[Here is the SSMS properties box for the policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlbuX.png)

When I create a sample stored procedure that conforms to this naming convention, the policy blocks the create statement.

Here is the sample stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_test
AS
print 'test'
```

Finally, here is the error output:

```
Policy 'policy_naming_usp_prefix' has been violated by 'SQLSERVER:\SQL\SERVERNAME\Databases\DBNAME\StoredProcedures\dbo.usp_test'.
This transaction will be rolled back.
Policy condition: '@Name LIKE 'usp_%''
Policy description: ''
Additional help: '' : ''
Statement: '
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_test
AS
print 'test''.
Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Procedure msdb.sys.sp_syspolicy_execute_policy, Line 69 [Batch Start Line 0]
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'target_query_expression', table 'msdb.dbo.syspolicy_policy_execution_history_details_internal'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What version?  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4037454/policy-based-management-policy-not-working-after-you-install-cu2

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-GDR) (KB4293803) - 14.0.2002.14 (X64)   Jul 21 2018 07:47:45   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Home 10.0 <X64> (Build 17134: )

Comment: You need to install CU2 for 2017. That should fix it. It’s referenced in that KB

Comment: That worked, thank you!

Comment: You bet. Good luck!!!!

Comment: @scsimon Hello scsimon. Since your comment solved the problem, perhaps it would be good to just add it as an answer.

Comment: Fair point @TT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments of being on the RTM version of 2017, you will need to updated to CU2 (at a minimum) as described [in this KB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4037454/policy-based-management-policy-not-working-after-you-install-cu2).

[Here's a link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4052574) to that cumulative update.

However, if you are using [Query Store you need CU3 instead.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4052987)

Lastly, you could just come "up to date" [and get CU13.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4466404/cumulative-update-13-for-sql-server-2017)